# C++11 `using` keyword: specialize template alias of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, using-directives

I had a problem today using the `using` keyword in `C++11`. I decided to use another approach now (added as comments in the example below). You can think of `X` as a matrix, of `Y` as a mixin and the aim is to access the tranposed matrix type of `X` in `Y`. Instead of `typedef`ing `X<B,A>` in `X<A,B>`, we take another approach that is more powerful and define a `Sibling` alias that takes two template parameters itself.

```
template <class A, class B>
struct X
{
  using Left = A;
  using Right = B;
  template <class T1, class T2>
  using Sibling = X<T1, T2>;
  // using Reversed = X<B, A>; // What I really want and use now. :-)
};

template <class A>
struct Y
{
  using Left = typename A::Left;
  using Right = typename A::Right;
  using AReverse = typename A::Sibling<Right, Left>; // Gives a compiler error
  // using AReverse2 = typename A::Reversed; // Works, of course.
};

using Z = X<int,double>::Sibling<double,int>; // Works
```

I tried compiling the code above with `g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -c` and it shows me the following error message:

```
t.cpp:16:9: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘AReverse’
t.cpp:16:9: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
t.cpp:16:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
t.cpp:16:18: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
```

I do not understand why a get an error message at all or how I could fix it. Could someone explain to me what the problem is?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to drop the `typename` and use `::template` instead:

```
using AReverse = A::template Sibling<Right, Left>;
```

The identifier to the right of `::` in this case (`Sibling`) is not a type, it's a template, and that's why this disambiguator is needed instead of `typename`.

Comment: This is incorrect. You also need the `typename` keyword here, because `A::Sibling<...>` is a dependently-scoped type name here.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what Clang says:

```
<stdin>:16:32: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'Sibling' as a dependent template name
  using AReverse = typename A::Sibling<Right, Left>; // Gives a compiler error
                               ^
                               template
```

Comment: Flippin' GCC and its flippin' errors... LOL